# Is the One just a prophecy for "free humans"?

Tags: the-matrix, prophecy

Is the One just a prophecy for "free humans"? If not, to whom else was this person important? What did the machines have to do with him?

**EDIT:**

I know this question is very broad and has multiple questions in them. But, I left it in the same state because of one precise reason, I may not recall all the relevant facts about the Matrix to narrow it down, but would like the answer to be consisting of that information. I guess that's too much to ask here and thus I am reducing the breadth of the question by adding some thoughts related to it:

If the One is the one for whom the free humans have been waiting on to save the world kind of a thing, the existence of the Oracle becomes a bit mysterious. The architect telling Neo that there have been several 'One's before him makes me feel that the machines too wait for the One to appear so that they can achieve some hidden goal of theirs at that time.

Comment: please do have the courtesy to leave a comment after down-voting!

Comment: I think the problem is that your question is too broad. These are not only technically three different questions but also logically, so it's hard to come up with one concise answer. Perhaps you can narrow and explain your question a bit more.

Comment: :( ok... Thanks for the comment @bitmask

Comment: As I understood it, the only ways the humans had any "prophecy of the One" was from the Oracle. She created the prophecy and the machines created the circumstances for "the One" to enter the Matrix. In the case of Neo the Oracle realized there was something different and helped him more than previous instances of "The One".

Answer (score 5):

In a sense yes, you could say that they wait for the "next" One, but for a different reason.

The machines found out that the humans accept being controlled, if they are given the slightest hint of a choice. The One is referred to by the machines as an "anomaly". Once in so many generations, the non-acceptance towards the Matrix by the humans would result in another incarnation of the One. Which each new One, the machines "tighten their grip" over humanity by learning how to improve the Matrix (that is, the acceptance of the Matrix).

However, this is only necessary, exactly because the humans have a tendency to generate Ones, once in a while. So, you could say that they are at least expecting the next One, but I wouldn't say the long for the next One in the way the "free humans" do.

The purpose of the Oracle is to understand this phenomenon, which is impossible for the Architect.

Comment: "Which each new One, the machines "tighten their grip" over humanity by learning how to improve the Matrix..." I like that quite a bit. The function of the One is now to return to the Source and reinsert the primary program, or some business like that. The Matrix takes the One in, looks him over to see what can get better, and reboots, starting the whole mess over again.

Comment: @bitmask Didn't they say that 'when the Matrix was created a man was born inside' i.e. the first 'One'. Was that a result of the program/code and an expected result? I guess that would still follow the idea as you say that 'another incarnation of the One'...